# Url Decode T-SQL function not translating out of ascii scope characters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ascii, urldecode, non-ascii-characters

I'm using this function to decode url encoded string :

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[UrlDecode](@url varchar(3072)) 
RETURNS varchar(3072) 
AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @Position INT,
        @Base CHAR(16),
        @High TINYINT,
        @Low TINYINT,
        @Pattern CHAR(21)

    SELECT  @Base = '0123456789abcdef',
        @Pattern = '%[%][0-9a-f][0-9a-f]%',
        @URL = REPLACE(@URL, '+', ' '),
        @Position = PATINDEX(@Pattern, @URL)

    WHILE @Position > 0
        SELECT  @High = CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(@URL, @Position + 1, 1), @Base COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS),
            @Low = CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(@URL, @Position + 2, 1), @Base COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS),
            @URL = STUFF(@URL, @Position, 3, CHAR(16 * @High + @Low - 17)),
            @Position = PATINDEX(@Pattern, @URL)

    RETURN  @URL + 
END
```

This works fine until it reaches special out of ascii scope characters. Example : `Wil+SG+1` will return `Wil SG 1` which is OK. While `Gen%C3%A8ve+11` returns `GenÃ¨ve 11` which is not what I expect (`Genève 11` is the expected result in this case).

another example :

```
select 'Gen%C3%A8ve+2+D%C3%A9p%C3%B4t', dbo.UrlDecode('Gen%C3%A8ve+2+D%C3%A9p%C3%B4t')
```

returns :

```
Gen%C3%A8ve+2+D%C3%A9p%C3%B4t   GenÃ¨ve 2 DÃ©pÃ´t
```

I've tried using NCHAR instead of CHAR but the result is the same. Do you know what I can do to support these extended ascii chars ?

Comment: I think this link may help -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585138/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-a-string-encoded-in-utf-8-and-vice-versa

Comment: Your routine does not compile because `RETURN @URL + ` is not a valid SQL statement.  What's supposed to be on that line?

Comment: Wait, ***why*** would you expect `Gen%C3%A8ve+11` to return `Genève 11`? Isn't UC+00C3 = "Ã"?  That would make `GenÃ¨ve 11` the correct answer.  And `Genève 11` doesn't even have the correct length?!?

Comment: @RBarryYoung No it's utf8 encoded so the correct result is è not Ã

Comment: Actually it's not UTF-8 encoded at all, nor does your function decode UTF-8 (which is a variable-width encoding).  The strings that you are displaying are what's called ***Percent Encoded*** (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), and what this algorithm does is correct Percent Decoding.  It doesn't do anything even remotely like valid UTF-8 Decoding.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I just quote wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding : "(For a non-ASCII character, it is typically converted to its byte sequence in UTF-8, and then each byte value is represented as above.)" ... Yes UTF-8

Comment: @Arno2501 Note the word "*typically*", which also means "*not always*".  The problem here is that you've just assumed that SQL Server uses UTF-8, but it doesn't.  SQL Server uses either ASCII or UCS-2.  When you are "Decoding" you have to decode into something that the decoding host/target uses or understands.  Otherwise it's not "decoding" but rather "re-coding".

Comment: Yes you are right not alway but in this case I have to decode the utf-8 to translate it correctly. Look at my own answer to see what I had to do to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this function that achieve exactly what I want :

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[UrlDecodeUTF8](@URL varchar(3072))
RETURNS varchar(3072)
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @Position INT,
        @Base CHAR(16),
        @Code INT,
        @Pattern CHAR(21)

    SELECT @URL = REPLACE(@URL, '%c3', '')

    SELECT  @Base = '0123456789abcdef',
        @Pattern = '%[%][0-9a-f][0-9a-f]%',
        @Position = PATINDEX(@Pattern, @URL)

    WHILE @Position > 0
        SELECT @Code = Cast(CONVERT(varbinary(4), '0x' + SUBSTRING(@URL, @Position + 1, 2), 1) As int),
            @URL = STUFF(@URL, @Position, 3, NCHAR(@Code + 64)),
            @Position = PATINDEX(@Pattern, @URL)

    RETURN REPLACE(@URL, '+', ' ')

END
```

Answer (score 3):

URLs are encoded in UTF-8. What your function does is simply replace the hex codes of the UTF-8 representation of the URL with the characters matching the hex codes.

What you really need is a function to replace URL-encoded UTF-8 to MSSQL UCS-2, as posted in this [answer on Social.MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/c1d1037a-b09c-4cca-a3c0-a99edb274eb9/).

Comment: You are absolutely right thanks for your answer but I realized that with mehdi's comment. thanks anyway.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect you'll need to play around with the collation, replacing UTF codes with some ascii equivalent. Here's an example I had in my code library:

```
REPLACE(CHAR(228) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN, CHAR(196), 'Y')
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I realized with mehdi's comment that it is utf8 encoded so I have to decode utf8